# AngularJS page don't shows

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

There is a main and secondary page, which is accessible from the main. Each page `header` is wrote on `html`, and then body loads as the `angularjs ng-app`, and processed using `RenderBody()`. The problem is that the controllers of two pages depends from the factory `ticketCache`:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('Application', [])
        .factory('ticketCache', ['$cacheFactory',function($cacheFactory) {
            var self = this;
            self.cache = $cacheFactory('ticketCache');

            return {
                get: function(key) {
                    return self.cache.get(key);
                },
                put: function(key, value) {
                    self.cache.put(key, value);
                },
                putList: function(list) {
                    list.forEach(function(item) {
                        self.cache.put(item.Id, item);
                    });
                },
                erase: function () {
                    self.cache.removeAll();
                }
            };
        }]);
})();
```

If I write `angular.module ('Application', [])`, then on the main page `body` don't shows, but on the secondary page `body` loads normally, if I remove and write like that `angular.module ('Application')`, it is the opposite, the main page `body` loads normally, but secondary page don't loads. Why it can be? How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module it's not clear why you have two separate pages here from how it sounds... SPA means you only have one head section for the page and a router in the angular app handles loading the appropriate templates and controller instances or getting providers from the injector.  In the link you'll see using one argument to angular.module acts as a getter, using two arguments creates a new module.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're explaining here, more code would help, but make sure that you are only using `angular.module('Application', [])` one time, after that you use `angular.module('Application')`.

Comment: modul is described as `(function () {
    angular.module('Application', ['route', 'ngSanitize', 'ngTagsInput', 'infinite-scroll'])`.
Controller of second page is (function () {
    `angular.module('Application')
        .controller('TimesheetCtrl', ['$scope', 'restService',`
Controller of main page is 
`(function () {
    angular.module('helpDesk')
        .controller('TicketsListCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'ticketsService', '$location',
            '$signalR', '$messagesMediator', '$pageTitle',`